# tail -f, awk and output to file >

Tags: bash, awk, sh, squid, tail

I am attempting to filter a log file and am running into issues, what I have so far is the following, which does not work,

```
tail -f /var/log/squid/accesscustom.log | awk '/username/;/user-name/ {print $1; fflush("")}' | awk '!x[$0]++' > /var/log/squid/accesscustom-filtered.log
```

The goal is to take a file that contains

```
ipaddress1 username
ipaddress7
ipaddress2 user-name
ipaddress1 username
ipaddress5
ipaddress3 username
ipaddress4 user-name
```

and save to accesscustom-filtered.log

```
ipaddress1
ipaddress2
ipaddress3
ipaddress4
```

It works without the output to accesscustom-filtered.log but something in the > isn't working right and the file ends up empty.

Edit: Changed the original example to be correct

Comment: I don't see a closing single quote (`'`) for that `awk` command. Is this what you have?

Comment: tail -f is a non terminating command, so I'm not sure you can pipe the output from it into a file like that

Comment: you can it's pretty funky stuff.

Comment: oops, I did have a closing ' and just didn't type it here, I also forgot to add the de-duplication part to the command here, see the new command now..someone probably has a better way of doing that then two awks in a row, but I couldn't figure it out

Answer (score 4):

Use `tee`:

```
tail -f /var/log/squid/accesscustom.log | awk '/username/;/user-name/ {print $1}' | tee /var/log/squid/accesscustom-filtered.log
```

See also: [Writing “tail -f” output to another file](https://superuser.com/questions/59497/writing-tail-f-output-to-another-file) and [Turn off buffering in pipe](http://www.perkin.org.uk/posts/how-to-fix-stdio-buffering.html)

Note: `awk` doesn't buffer like `grep` in the superuser example, so you shouldn't need to do anything special with your `awk` command. ([more info](http://www.perkin.org.uk/posts/how-to-fix-stdio-buffering.html))

Comment: never heard of tee, let me try it out...note the new command in my original post, forgot part of it when posting

Comment: doesn't work, I did one command without the tee...and one with it, to a file. The one without the tee outputted correctly to the screen, the one with the tee didn't add to the filtered file

Comment: looks like the second awk breaks it, without that it appears to work

Comment: nevermind, doesn't work without the second awk either, it appeared to work last time but it doesn't actually follow the log file, it must have just worked using the first tail output but it didn't work on the rolling

Comment: looks like with one search statement in the awk it works, but when I put the second search statement in, it breaks the output to the file, the second search statement really does have a "-" in it, does it need escaped out or something?

Comment: looks like "-" doesn't need a escape